# Save pictures in swift where users can't access

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nsdocumentdirectory

I have an application that allows the user to take a photo and it saves immediately, however they are currently stored in the application documents directory which is accessible through programs like iFunBox. Here is how I save the images.

```
        var imageName = "SomeGeneratedImageName.jpeg"
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
        let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as NSString
        let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)
        var data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
        data.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

Where do I save images so the user cannot access them even through programs such as iFunBox?

***UPDATE - Answer Used***

Based of of [zaph's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451475/zaph) answer i encrypted the pictures before saving and when reading, using [RNEncrytor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) Here is my save function:

```
        var imageName = "someImageName.jpeg"
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
        let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as NSString
        let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)
        var data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) //change 1 for compression
        let encryptedData = RNEncryptor.faireseEncryptData(data, password: "password", error: nil)
        encryptedData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

and

```
    var imageName = "thatSameImageName.jpeg"
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as NSString
    let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)
    var decryptedImg = RNDecryptor.faireseDecryptData(NSData(contentsOfFile: path), password: "theSamePass", error: nil)
    if(decryptedImg != nil) {
        //alert
    var image: UIImage? = UIImage(data: decryptedImg)
}
```

also to get this to work in swift there was some issue with the AES256 so i added some classes to the `RNEncryptor.h`, `RNEncryptor.m`, `RNDecryptor.h`, and the `RNDecryptor.m`

```
//To RNEncrpytor.h
+ (NSData *)faireseEncryptData:(NSData *)data password:(NSString *)password error:(NSError **)error;
```

.

```
//To RNEncryptor.m
+ (NSData *)faireseEncryptData:(NSData *)data password:(NSString *)password error:(NSError **)error {
return [RNEncryptor encryptData:data withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:password error:error]; }
```

.

```
//To RNDecryptor.h
+ (NSData *)faireseDecryptData:(NSData *)data password:(NSString *)password error:(NSError **)error;
```

.

```
//TO RNDecryptor.m
+ (NSData *)faireseDecryptData:(NSData *)data password:(NSString *)password error:(NSError **)error {
return [RNDecryptor decryptData:data withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:password error:error]; }
```

Comment: it's their device. there's nothing you can do to prevent them from snooping around if they so choose.

Comment: So server uploading is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Saying the images on a server has it's own problems. How secure is the server and admin access? The server can be attacked without possession of the device. The server becomes a more tempting target since it will contain a great number of photos. There is a liability if the server is breached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save with `writeToFile:options:error:` with a `NSDataWritingOptions` of `NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete` or explicitly encrypt and decrypt as needed saving the password in the Keychain, see RNCryptor for a good encryption routine.

Generally saving large data items in a database is not a good solution.

Comment: So technically i could save images to the documents directory encrypted with a password on them using this method?

Comment: Yes, saving encrypted versions of the photos in the Documents directory is secure. RNCryptor is a good encryption routine, it does all the tedious things that need to be done. The Keychain is easy to use from Swift because the key is the weak pot. Do checkout if `NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete` is sufficient for your needs because it is dead simple handles the encryption key transparently.

Answer (score 2):

If you save it anywhere on device, the users can access them.

So there are two roads that you can take at this fork. 
Keep it encrypted when you save it to device. And decrypt when your application wants to. (look up [sqlCipher for iPhone](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/) it's super safe)
Keep it at the server, and only download to show, but never save.

Comment: Generally saving large data items in a database is not an advisable solution. Use a database if you need database capabilities, not for encryption.

Comment: If you need to encrypt stuff, RNCrytpor is a good choice. https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor